# Everytime when i clicked on add button one movable textfield with radio button need to create right side in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwUH4.png)
Like this i need to get. but binding the value from text field i have done. but parallel when user clicks on add button adjustable textbox with radio button need to create same time.

tried some logic for binding the value and displaying the data in the right side. but struck near the
when user clicks on add button adjustable textbox with radio button need to create same time. as look in the picture

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
 
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

 
  render() {
    return(  
      // <div id="content">
      <div className="container">
      <div id="left">
        <div className="box">
          <label className="label">compose question</label>
          <input className="input is-medium" type='text' id='input' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <label className="label">MULTIPLE CHOICE OPTION</label>
        </div>  
        <div id="right">
          <p className="input-value"> <span className="highlight">{this.state.value}</span></p>
          </div>
         


      </div>
      // </div>
     
       
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.3.2/css/bulma.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.3.2/css/bulma.min.css.map'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think no one would understand your problem due to bad English.

Comment: Sorry for that. Can you see the image which I attached in the description. I have tried the above code for binding and displaying the value which I entered in the textbox.

Comment: My question is I want one button, so when user clicked on the button one textfield need to create and one radio button also at the same time.     Please see the image provided in the description so that u can understand my question clearly.